# TLS 1.2 set cipher list

Tags: ssl, openssl, boost-asio

I would like to set the TLS 1.2 configuration as below in my linux application.

```
ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

I know of the `API SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(SSL *ssl, const char *str);` My question is how do I set more than one cipher using this API. Should I call this API twice or how else?

Currently I am setting only one configuration like this:

```
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384)
```

How do I set both the configurations as listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ciphers.html  "The cipher list consists of one or more cipher strings separated by colons. Commas or spaces are also acceptable separators but colons are normally used."

I would say 'ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256'

Comment: Thanks. I have a follow up question. I have been advised to use the method TLS_server_method( ) instead of fixing the method to TLS v1.2 considering the various clients that can connect. How do I then set the cipher suite in case the client connects in TLSv1.2 mode to ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.